# ftp-server accessible only via command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ftp

I have a filezilla ftp server on a Windows Web Server 2008R2, which is accessible only via command prompt. I am unable to connect to the ftp server via any client. The port 21 on the server is open. Is there anything which I might be missing about the ftp server's setting ?

Best Regards,
Rahul

Comment: What do you mean "is accessible only via command prompt"?

Answer (score 1):

If your FTP Server is behind a firewall it might be to do with whether your client is using Passive connections or not.  If your client has this option then try turning it on/off.

That said, the passiveness shouldn't affect your ability to login, just to transfer files.

Can you connect but not transfer?  Or not even connect?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what IP your connecting to from the local machine.. I'm betting it's a firewall or a binding issue and your connecting to localhost